# Consulta SQL com array

Tags: sql, array, sql-server

Estou tentado fazer uma consulta SQL passando vários valores e estou tendo o erro abaixo:

Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Minha query:

```
declare @Ids VARCHAR(500)

set @Ids = ('19290992743, 2600586709')

declare @query VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @query = 'SELECT * FROM [TABELA DE CLIENTES] WHERE CPF IN '

SELECT @query = @query + '(' + @Ids + ')'

print @query

EXEC (@query)
```

Passando apenas um valor na variável @Ids funciona. Ex:

```
set @Ids = ('19290992743')
```

A coluna CPF está como varchar no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro é porque "o id" que você está consultando não são dois (*'19290992743'* e *'2600586709'*), mas sim um (*'19290992743, 2600586709'*).

Separe os *ids* pois são *strings* diferentes:

```
set @Ids = ('19290992743', '2600586709')
```

detlahe: caso você receba esses *ids* de outra aplicação, precisaria tratar essa *string*, algo tipo

```
set @Ids = STRING_SPLIT('19290992743, 2600586709', ', ')
```

Comment: Mas passando dessa forma da erro na query:

Mensagem 102, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 3
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Use o print @query para ver o sql gerado , ajuda a corrigir. Importante também saber , creio , qual o "type" de CPF na tabela em questão.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui fazer dessa forma:

```
/* Valores */
declare @Ids VARCHAR(500)
set @Ids = ('1471156710,19290992743')

/* Select */
SELECT * FROM [TABELA DE CLIENTES]
WHERE CPF IN (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Ids, ','))
```

Comment: vale marcar a resposta como aceita pra pergunta não ficar em aberto